# Displaying a specific part of list in Android

Tags: android, listactivity, selecteditem, radiobuttonlist

I have a list activity. This displays a list of radio button selections. 
When I select something, I save that selection and when I return to the list, the same radiobutton is highlighted.

Is there a way, to display the part of the list that has the selection when the list comes up for the first time, instead of displaying the start of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listView.setSelection(int savedPosition)` to set the selected position.